# What trick was used to transform this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

I found this transformation in the solution set for some integration exercises. It looks like substitution, but it's written so I don't understand what the substitution was.
$$\int_0^1 \frac{-2x_2^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}dx_2 = \int_0^1x_2\frac{d}{dx_2}\left(\frac{1}{x_1^2+x_2^2}\right)dx_2$$
I'm confused: why is there a differentiation in the integral? What is happening here?

Comment: If you differentiat that $\frac{1}{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ w.r.t $x_2$ you get exactly $-\frac{2x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}$ so that those integrals are really the same. It isn't the substitution, it's just rewritting integral, so that it is easier to see how to apply integration by parts.

Comment: @DominikKutek been doing too many substitution exercises... Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}[1]{\; \mathrm{d} #1}$
More accurately it is a partial derivative. There's no substitution here - just evaluate the derivative on the right.
$$
\int_0^1 x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \left(\frac{1}{x_1^2 + x_2^2}\right) \d{x_2} = \int_0^1 x_2 \left(\frac{-2x_2}{(x_1^2 + x_2^2)^2}\right) \d{x_2} = \int_0^1  \frac{-2x_2^2}{(x_1^2 + x_2^2)^2} \d{x_2}
$$